# Enable div based on the value presence

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to enable div based on the value exists. i have a template as follows, if availableTickets is null or zero i need to show it as,

```
 <div ng-if="DetailEvent.listing?.availableTickets == 0">
      <div > No tickets available</div>
 </div>
```

if it has some values i need to show this div

```
 <div ng-if="DetailEvent.listing?.availableTickets > 0">
      <div >Only <b>{{DetailEvent.listing?.availableTickets}}</b> tickets left</div>
 </div>
```

both are not working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for Angular.

```
 <div *ngIf="DetailEvent.listing?.availableTickets > 0">
      <div >Only <b>{{DetailEvent.listing?.availableTickets}}</b> tickets left</div>
 </div>
```

Note the star and lack of hyphen.